# In R assign function dependent on value of argument

Tags: r

Apologies for the somewhat vague question - I feel that this should be possible, but am not sure how to go about it.

I am trying to speed up a model fitting function.  I'm aware that several parts of my code check certain aspects of the model (e.g. is the model stratified or not), and that checking these model aspects at each iteration slows down the code. So rather than checking stratification within each iteration, or coding separate loops for the case where the model is stratified or is not, I was hoping there was a way to set a function to one of a couple of options dependent on the model structure.  Then the same code could be used, but the function called within the iteration would be different.

Specifically, is it possible to code different versions of a function for different cases (e.g. a function `f()`, to code a version for a stratified model `f.strat()` and a version for non-stratified `f.nonstrat`, and use an argument in the main model fitting function call to specify what `f` should be?  Something along the lines of:

```
if(strat){
   f<-f.strat(...)
}else{
   f<-f.nonstrat(...)
}
```

I'd like the functions (e.g. `f.strat` and `f.nonstrat`) not to be coded locally in the model fitting function.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - I'm sorry I don't have an example

Comment: Do you know ahead of time if the model is stratified or not? This sounds like a textbook cause for S3.

Comment: I'm writing a program that needs to be able to take cases where the model is and is not stratified - but that is only one example of several of model aspects that alter the model fitting algorithm- so I'd rather not code separate algorithms for each case as there are so many combinations